# Working example of NetStream.videoSampleAccess?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, p2p, netstream

I'm currently building a browser-based application using Stratus. So far everything is working fine and I understand how it all works.

The problem is when I try to manipulate the pixel data of the incoming remote video stream using `BitmapData.draw()`. What happens is that I get a sandbox security error, which is understandable.

To solve this I wanted to use the new `NetStream.videoSampleAccess` property, but I just can't seem to get it working. It doesn't matter which netstream object I set the property on, or where I set it, I get the same error message.

> The `NetStream` Object is invalid. This may be due to a failed `NetConnection`.

What's interesting is I can achieve the same functionality by using the following trick:

```
NetStream.send("|RtmpSampleAccess",true,true);
```

Does anyone have a working example with `NetStream.videoSampleAccess`? Or any idea why I could be receiving this error?

**PS:** I have also posted this question in the Adobe forums if you think you've seen it before. I'm hoping the community here is a little more varied than the tiny sub-forum I had to post this in at Adobe.